# Reading a comma delimited list from .txt file

Tags: matlab

I have a comma delimited list of float numbers in a .txt file. I plan on reading that file and plotting the points for a visual.

The .txt file is laid out like this

```
4, 0.0, 0.4
-0.4, 0.4, 0.4
-0.0, 0.4, 0.4
-0.0, 0.0, 0.4
-0.0, 0.4, -0.0
-0.0, 0.4, 0.4
-0.8, 0.4, 0.4
```

This is the code I'm using in Matlab

```
fileID = fopen('data.txt','r');
A = textscan(fileID, '%f %f %f', 'Delimiter', ',');

Column1 = A{1}
Column2 = A{2}
Column3 = A{3}

figure(1)
 plot(A{1})
 hold on;
 plot(A{1}, '*')
```

What I'm getting as a result is

```
Column1 =    
     4   

Column2 =    
     0   

Column3 =
    0.4000
```

This code should be set up correctly (from sample code I've used [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html)) 
Instead it is just returning the data from the very first line of the file and nothing else.  I'm not sure what I'm missing to make this work. Any solution will be fine, or anything to point me in the right direction will be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `csvread`?

Comment: @Suever Can I use csvread with a .txt file? I've never heard of this function, so I don't know the underlying details of what type of files it can handle.

Comment: A CSV file *is* a text file. The file extension is irrelevant.